# find searched user name in full user name

Tags: php, ajax

i am trying to search a user name from a list of user name such that it can give me the results accordingly but via php . i am already fetching a list of user names in array in php . i just want to search the user typed name from those list of usernames .

i use `ajax` and `onkeyup` to send the search term via ajax to the page where all those user names exist. i know how to do it in mysql using `like` but how to search it inside a php variable such that . suppose user searched 'ron' and there is a variable `$user='ron martin';`
then how to search that search term from the variable `$user`. and also that it avoids the spaces in between full names

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: Can you give any examples of the data/tables/functions? Your explanation is a bit confusing without anything.

Comment: If your list is not that big, I'd prefer JavaScript for filtering, because you don't need to request your server. The work will be done by the clients (browser).

Comment: actually i am fetching friends from fb and they are in array i know how to display them separate and organized . its just that i have user names in variables so its easy to search from there. and yes the list is big around 500 plus

Answer (score 0):

You want to search for a string in a string, you need

```
strstr();

string strstr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = false ] )
```

for that:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php
```

Comment: it does not matches words properly :(

Comment: What do you mean? strstr() will find 'ron' in 'ron martin'. Unless it is differently capitalized, then you need stristr()

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the username to your php code, use `in_array()` to look it up in your array of names:

```
if in_array($user, $array_of_names) {
    ...
```